# i am unable to implement Nativescript Autocomplete module in nativescript2 angular2?

Tags: angular, nativescript

i want to implement autocomplete module in my nativescript angular2 app but i am not able to do that i have used following code as below i want to suggest user after typing initial words in textfield

Here is my component.html-

```
    <AutoComplete items="{{list}}" 
                  (itemTap)="itemTapped($event)" 
                  backgroundColor="yellow"> </AutoComplete>
```

Here is my component.ts

This is my ts file i am developing `nativescript2` `angular2` `typescript` app and i am not able to implement autocomplete module in my app so please help me.

I have written only related code

```
export class RegistrationComponent implements OnInit{
     let AutoComplete = require("nativescript-autocomplete");
     item:Array<string> = ['1','2','3','4']
     itemTapped(args){}
}
```

Comment: with only this code you are getting error?

Comment: no i have not included other part of code what i am using for  autocomplete code it is please tell me how to use autocomplete module in nativesccript2 angular2 using typescript app